# I need help putting values from one vector into another in R

Tags: r

I have two vectors in R

```
Vector 1 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
Vector 2 
1 1 3 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to put the values from vector 2 into vector 1 but into specific positions so that vector 1 becomes

```
1 1 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

I need to do this in one line of code. I tried doing:

```
vector1[1:3,6:10] = vector2[1:3,4:8]
```

but I am getting the error "incorrect number of dimensions".

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector1[c(1:3,6:10)] = vector2[c(1:3,4:8)]
> vector1
 [1] 1 1 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```

Answer (score 0):

We may use negative indexing

```
vector1[-(4:5)] <-  vector2
vector1
 [1] 1 1 3 0 0 1 1 1 1 1
```